# all available sampler parameters and usages

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I'm studying about sampler in opengl.

There are a series of APIs to setting sampler parameter like glSamplerParameteri(GLuint *sampler*, GLenum *pname*, GLint *param*).

And they can take various value of *pname* (like GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), and each of them can take some proper *param* (GL_CLAMP or GL_REPEAT for GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S).

At this point, I am curious about all the available parameter names (*pname*) and their usages.

I've tried to search, but I can't.
can anyone give me some explanations about this? simple links are welcome.

additionally, I can't access to http://www.opengl.org !! what's the matter on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping modes

- GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S
- GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T
- GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R

Minification and magnification filtering modes

- GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER
- GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER

LoD and Depth comparison parameters

- GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD
- GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD
- GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS
- GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE
- GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC

These are the allowed enums for *pname*. [This page](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/texturemaps.html) has a good explanation on most of these.

Comment: @alleysark: Sampling is not a particularly complicated feature (parameter wise)... you have texture coordinate manipulation, LOD selection, filtering and sometimes depth comparison (shadow samplers). Even GL4 does not add any new *sampler object* state, though it really should -- the new stencil texture mode should by all accounts be a sampler state, but it is not for some reason. By the way, when the Khronos website is working again, I would suggest you take a look at the GL 3.3 spec. under the state table for ***Sampler Objects*** toward the end of the document.